# Find max time delta after sorting data and applying groupby

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, timedelta, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame (df) that contains two rows with multiple entries per 'name':

```
                     name                           date
       Official Press FRC        2015-02-19 20:30:00.000
   Other Publications BOJ        2015-04-16 07:00:00.000
           Bank of Russia        2015-06-11 09:44:37.000
```

I would like to find the maximum difference in 'dates' for each 'name'. My approach to this was to try and sort the dates while simultaneously grouping by name and then take the difference using .diff(). Below is the code I tried:

```
grouped = df.sort_values('date').groupby('name')
differences = grouped.diff()
```

I also tried to approach the problem by constructing a pivot table:

```
grouped = df.pivot(columns='name', values='date')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need custom function with `diff` and `max` for max timedelta:

```
#if necessary convert to datetime 
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df1 = df.sort_values('date')
        .groupby('name')['date'].apply(lambda x: x.diff().max())
        .reset_index(name='max_diff')
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get this error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: I think first need convert dates to datetime, check edited answer.

Comment: sorry, forget for column.

Comment: If I wanted to find the average (instead of the max) would I just do x.diff().mean() when applying the lambda function? [Also, I am going to accept your answer as soon as stackoverflow lets me :-)]

Comment: With mean it is complicated... Give me some time.

Comment: Thanks, that's great!